# Obtain currency symbol unicode character from JSON response to present in UILabel

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, json, unicode

How to store Unicode character like `'EURO SIGN' (U+20AC)` in MySQL db and than transfer it to ios application in JSON for showing it in `UILabel`, for example.

Just hardcoded `NSString` like `@"\u20AC"` for local application needs works great.
But storing `\u20AC` in db leads to \u20AC in result after transferring. Other manipulations with received value has no effect.

*In short* -  how to store currency codes on server side and transfer them to ios application via JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, use the second argument thus:

```
json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

to avoid getting the `\u` codes.